# How to create semicircle chart in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am trying to create a graph like the one shown in the image, I have been trying for a while but I have not been able to do it yet, for that I started using canvas, I have already implemented a piechart graph, but I have had difficulty making it semicircle, I have I have been looking in various places but I have not been able to do it, the most I have managed is to try to implement what appears in this https://semicolonspace.com/jetpack-compose-chart-circular/ article but without success, someone has already been able to do it and can you explain or show me how to do it?

[image]

Comment: You just have to draw an arc, changing the color at specified angles

Comment: @Rafsanjani Yes, that is exactly what I have tried, but so far I have not been able to do it, I understand that to achieve that a kind of formula or something similar is used to obtain the angles, I have problems with that